# Rspec model tests fail due to ENOMEM on Google Compute VM, but not on physical machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rspec, google-compute-engine, kvm

I frequently run into memory allocation errors when running rspec model tests on my Google Compute server with 3.75 GB of RAM that I don't get when running the same tests on a normal machine with 2 GB of RAM. The command I use is 'rspec spec/models' so that all the tests are run. This doesn't occur when I run any other kind of rspec test.

On my normal machine only 2 out of 584 tests fail (which at present is the expected behaviour). However, 148 failures occur when I use the Google Compute server, and this is an example of the output I get from the top:

```
Run options: include {:focus=>true}

All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:focus=>true}
....................F.FF.......................................................................................................................FFF.FF.F.............................................................................................................................F..F.F.F..FF.F...F.FF..F..F..F....F.FFF..FF.F.FF.FFFF.F.FFFFF.FF..F.FF.FFF...F.FFF...FFFF.FFFF.F.F.FF...............................................FF..F.F.FF.FF.FF.F...F.F.F..F.F.F.F......F.F...F.F.F.FF..FF.F.FFF..FF.FF.F..F..........FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
An error occurred in an after(:all) hook.
  Errno::ENOMEM: Cannot allocate memory - rm -rf /home/patrick/terrabase/imperial/files/test
  occurred at /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@imperialhorizons/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/agnostics.rb:7:in ``'

.
An error occurred in an after(:all) hook.
  Errno::ENOMEM: Cannot allocate memory - rm -rf /home/patrick/terrabase/imperial/files/test
  occurred at /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@imperialhorizons/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/agnostics.rb:7:in ``'

....
An error occurred in an after(:all) hook.
  Errno::ENOMEM: Cannot allocate memory - rm -rf /home/patrick/terrabase/imperial/files/test
  occurred at /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@imperialhorizons/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/agnostics.rb:7:in ``'

.
An error occurred in an after(:all) hook.
  Errno::ENOMEM: Cannot allocate memory - rm -rf /home/patrick/terrabase/imperial/files/test
  occurred at /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@imperialhorizons/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/agnostics.rb:7:in ``'

.
```

...which carries on like that until the 'Failures' section at the bottom:

```
142) LibraryBarcodeImport#process_row update existing student if the cid matches should set the imported count to 1
     Failure/Error: let(:library_barcode_import) { FactoryGirl.build(:library_barcode_import, log_text: "", imported_count: 0) }
     Errno::ENOMEM:
       Cannot allocate memory - file -b --mime '/home/patrick/terrabase/imperial/spec/testfiles/barcodes.xlsx'
     # ./spec/models/library_barcode_import_spec.rb:57:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/library_barcode_import_spec.rb:103:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What I have noticed is that some tests fail before they are run. For instance, line 57 in library_barcode_import_spec.rb is:

```
let(:library_barcode_import) { FactoryGirl.build(:library_barcode_import, log_text: "", imported_count: 0) }
```

...and line 103 is in a 'before' statement:

```
before do
    library_barcode_import.process_row(spreadsheet_row, 1, checking )
end
```

Software:

- Ruby 1.9.3-p194
- Rails 3.2.22
- Rspec 2.13.1

Virtual machine specs:

- n1-standard-1 (1 vCPU, 3.75 GB memory)
- CPU Platform: Intel Sandy Bridge
- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, kernel: 3.19.0-43-generic
- Hard disk: 10 GB

Physical machine specs:

- Toshiba Satellite Pro A300
- CPU: Intel Pentium Dual CPU T2390 @ 1.86 GHz
- OS: Linux Mint 17.3 64-bit

There's no shortage of RAM available on the VM, as you can see from the output of 'free -m':

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3700        947       2753         14         80        531
-/+ buffers/cache:        336       3364
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Output from 'dmesg | grep -i virtual' shows that the server relies on KVM:

```
[    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on KVM
```

I haven't found anything remotely useful for dealing with the problem when searching on Google. Does anyone know what might be causing this?